# Error DiskSize Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a function that checks if the drive (CD / DVD, USB key, floppy are OK) ...

It worked perfectly ... If it is less than 0 ... It returns that there is no drive connected ...

The big problem, I removed my pendrive, without ejecting;;; I pulled the pendrive ... Hence the DiskSize function returns the following error:

> there is the disk in the drive. please insert a disk into drive device

How do I fix this error ... because the function is working properly ... Just DiskSize that is generating this error, the fact that I was puzado the stick without Eject ...

```
// Check if drive is OK
function DriveOK (Drive: Char): boolean;
var
I: byte;
space: integer;
begin
   Drive: = upcase (Drive);
   not if (Drive in ['A' .. 'Z']) then Begin
     raise Exception.Create ('incorrect Unit');
   end;

   I: = Ord (Drive) - 64;
   if (DiskSize(I) >= 0) then Begin
      Result: = false;
   End Else Begin
      Result: = true;
   end;
end;
```

My system is Windows 7 64bit ... I found, the error is generated since removed the Printer Memory Card ... But the problem is that this card compatilhado Network ... When I remove the network share ... it does not generate the error ...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can we have a complete program that gives the output that you show.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have? The reason why I'm asking this is that last week when I have installed Windows 8.1 to my moms new computer (I have never used Windows 8.1 before) I noticed that each new USB flash drive, or External HDD gets its own drive letter assigned even if I already removed previosly used USB flash drive or External HDD. I even noticed that Windows 8.1 lists removable devices like USB flash drives or External HSS's in device manager with the drive letter that it was assigned to them.

Comment: So it is posible that your program is trying to retrieve disk size from a disconected device becouse windows has still a drkive letter assigned to it. Now unfortunately I don't have acces to my moms computer to test this out.

Comment: Why would you return `DriveOK=True` when the specified drive is not available?

Comment: I return ... for CD / DVD drives that exist but are not ready to use return (-1) ... the other drives return, where I can use them (> = 0) ...

Comment: You should set the error mode at process startup once and for all

Comment: Yes, one *should*, but that does not mean that most people actually *do*.

Comment: @abcd: Again, why would you have a function named `DriveOK()` return `True` when the drive is NOT ready, and return `False` when the drive IS ready? Either your logic is backwards, or your function is misnamed.

Comment: @Remy We can only offer advice of good practice. We cannot enforce it. We can lead the horse to water. We cannot force it to drink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn off Windows' internal error reporting to disable the popup error dialog:

```
function DriveOK(Drive: Char): Boolean;
var
  I: byte;
  mode: UINT;
begin
  Drive := UpCase(Drive);
  if not (Drive in ['A' .. 'Z']) then begin
    raise Exception.Create('incorrect Unit');
  end;

  I := Ord(Drive) - 64;

  mode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  mode := SetErrorMode(mode or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  try
    if (DiskSize(I) >= 0) then begin
      Result := False;
    end else begin
      Result := True;
    end;
  finally
    SetErrorMode(mode);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function DriveOK(Drive: Char): Boolean;
var
  I: byte;
  mode: DWORD;
begin
  Drive := UpCase(Drive);
  if not (Drive in ['A' .. 'Z']) then begin
    raise Exception.Create ('incorrect Unit');
  end;

  I := Ord(Drive) - 64;

  SetThreadErrorMode(GetThreadErrorMode() or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS, @mode);
  try
    if (DiskSize(I) >= 0) then begin
      Result := False;
    end else begin
      Result := True;
    end;
  finally
    SetThreadErrorMode(mode, nil);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I can not understand why a function DriveOK() returns False if the DiskSize > 0 ? The DiskSize function gives the size in bytes of the given Drive. If the drive is invalid, or no media, -1 is returned ! and your function DriveOK() returns True if the drive is invalid (-1)?

Comment: I saw that, but I left it as-is because that is what the OP's original code did. All I did was add the code to disable/re-enable the OS error mode.

Comment: Really ... . it's because I'm starting in Delphi  ... It was enough to put `Result: = DiskSize (I)> = 0;` ... It worked perfectly ... but the tip on `SetErrorMode`, will help me in future codes ... Thanks ...

Answer (score -1):

Hey friends it occurred because windows 7 stores some cache files in any pendrive inserted and when you pull it out without ejecting those files gets mishandled and causes a lots of problem. You can avoid this by disabling 'cache files storage' on your pendrive in windows os. For it's quite complex and long process I am providing a link you can use to avoid such problems further 
 http://www.rybersoft.com/2016/05/how-to-disable-write-caching-by-windows.html